# The best way to represent a tree structure on iPad

Tags: treeview, ipad

I am developing an iPad application and I need to represent tree structure (a simple tree structure which has root, parent and child nodes) on iPad. Is there a final solution for such kind situations, like TreeView?

Answer (score 2):

There is not an official "TreeView" control provided by the iOS SDK.  However, if you want to go about creating one yourself, Jon Limjap has posted a blog about doing so here:

[TreeView Blog Post](http://dotnet.kapenilattex.com/?p=566)